# VSCode missing std::as_const()?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, include

I have double checked several times that I am running either C++17 or above, yet this problem keeps occurring and I really don't understand why.

I am simply trying to call a const member function by using std::as_const(), which shouldn't be causing any fuss. Maybe it's missing from the utility library? But how could that be?

If anyone has an idea why this is happening I'd appreciate an answer.

[VSCode telling me Utility library doesn't have std::as_const()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ci4cA.jpg)

Comment: Note that vscode does not compile the source, it is your (remote) machine's compiler who is likely missing the feature,.

Comment: @HenriqueBucher Oh, I see. I'm using mingw as my compiler, maybe I have to reinstall it?

Comment: Try to compile by hand. Do you know how to?

Comment: @HenriqueBucher I'm afraid I do not. Does that mean writing your own compiler?

Comment: Aha no. Open a terminal and type `g++ main.cpp -o main.exe` and let me know what you got

Comment: Ahh right. Okay, I did and I got the same error message:

main.cpp: In function 'void f(int_buffer)':
main.cpp:24:25: error: 'as_const' is not a member of 'std'
     for (const int* i = std::as_const(buf).begin(); i != buf.end(); i ++){

Comment: Can you tell me what version it is?  `g++ --version`

Comment: gcc (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0

maybe it's an old one?

Comment: I'm afraid it is. December 21, 2016 https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html
You should definitely update. How did you install mingw? By itself or within MSYS2?

Comment: I think by itself. I didn't go to the conventional download source as that one didn't work.
Alright, I will update. That was probably why it didn't work. Should I download it off the link you provided?

Comment: No, that site you will download gcc sources only. Compiling compilers is a marathon. You really need to update or upgrade mingw.

Comment: No problem. I will summarize this in an answer in case you wish to accept that.

Comment: Note that the official VSCode documentation tells you to use msys2 to install MinGW. The current MinGW available on msys2 has gcc-12.2: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)

Answer (score 0):

To summarize the back and forth in the comments:

1. Visual Studio Code relies on an external compiler to build and analize sources
2. Your compiler is the one that is likely old, not Visual Studio Code
3. Verify that your compiler is current
4. Update to a new compiler by upgrading MinGW.

In this case OP had an old compiler gcc 6.3.0 from Dec/2016 that did not support the features he wanted.